# Sometimes Logcat shows "GREF has increased to 301"

Tags: java, android, debugging

I am just doing a simple POST through an HttpConnection, and Logcat sometimes responds by =
 "GREF has increased to 301"

what does it mean?
thanks.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to fix somethings when i post o i request a service

Comment: In that case you should ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: ah ok ! thanks to notice me, too bad, coz i am just starting enjoy the work around this forum ! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a debugging message from the Dalvik VM.  When CheckJNI is enabled (which it is by default on the emulator and "-eng" builds), the cap for JNI global references is reduced to 2000, and the VM will occasionally emit status messages as the level rises and falls.  The purpose is to make egregious global reference leaks obvious.

If you're not writing native code with the NDK, you can ignore the messages.

Comment: I'm getting error gref has increased 201 when i send base_64 string using web service, any idea to solve this issue.